# d3.js load data dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a file with 5 variables and data for 10 years. Each year has about 8000 data points (for every hour of a day in a year) for each variable.  So when I use all these data (8000*10*5 = 400k) to create an interactive line plot using D3.js, there is a delay in loading the viz. Similar to http://bl.ocks.org/DStruths/9c042e3a6b66048b5bd4  .

To make plots load faster, I can just query the average of a day for every year for every variable and plot them, to begin with.

My questions is if I want to zoom in to a day , say 8/1/2010, how can I query the database for those hourly data of that day?  The database I am using is cassandra and I am also using node.js to query from cassandra.